Heatmap Italy by province per eur amount
I have R 4.4.0 on my laptop. I have data in terms of EUR per italian provinces (so, a csv file with two columns, Italian province and EUR amount for a variable).
I would like to present this data in a nice heatmap (for example, from dark red for the higher amount to light green for the lower).
I cannot find any specific question in the past for matching my request, is there someone so kind having code ready for this presentation?
I tried several tentatives with ggplot2, but i dont even manage to build the map, and i cannot figure out how to add the heatmpa based on my table.
